# Need to create conditional validation using Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yup

I have the following dataset

```
{
    "json_schema": {
        "properties": {
            "analyst_time": {
                "description": "Analyst Task Time, in minutes",
                "is_duration_field": true,
                "mouseover_help": "...",
                "order": 11,
                "required_positive": true,
                "type": "integer"
            }
        },
        "required_one_of": [
            [
                "analyst_time",
                "instrument_time"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

`properties` object includes all of the fields

Form fields and validation are formed from `properties`.
Need to extend the validation.
It is required to add conditional validation to the field sets from the `required_one_of` array so that the fields from this set are required until at least one of them is filled.

I tried to do it with `yup.when`, but I got an error, since the fields have a looped relationship
[image]